# Stream write and read?

Tags: c#, stream, streaming, naudio

I am searching for the solution to make this code thread safe:

```
private Stream ms = new MemoryStream();
public void PlayMp3FromUrl(string url)
{
    new Thread(delegate(object o)
    {
        var response = WebRequest.Create(url).GetResponse();
        using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[65536]; // 64KB chunks
            int read;
            while ((read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                var pos = ms.Position;
                ms.Position = ms.Length;
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                ms.Position = pos;
            }
        }
    }).Start();

    // Pre-buffering some data to allow NAudio to start playing
    while (ms.Length < 65536*10)
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

    ms.Position = 0;
    using (WaveStream blockAlignedStream = new BlockAlignReductionStream(WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(new Mp3FileReader(ms))))
    {
        using (WaveOut waveOut = new WaveOut(WaveCallbackInfo.FunctionCallback()))
        {
            waveOut.Init(blockAlignedStream);
            waveOut.Play();
            while (waveOut.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can not change `ms.Position` for `ms.Write` while you are at the same time using NAudio to play it, yes? Any solutions to make it thread safe?

Also if the stream is endless or very big, how to clear already played stream part?

Comment: Why not use a delegate as a callback to your thread? After you receive data, check if it meets your requirements and if it does, invoke the callback. That's what I would do. Another thing would be to make an `AutoResetEvent` and trigger it when the requirements are met.

Answer (score 1):

there is an example of streaming an MP3 from a URL in the NAudio source code (look in the NAudioDemo project at the [MP3 streaming demo](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/tree/master/NAudioDemo/Mp3StreamingDemo)). My recommended approach is to fill a `BufferedWaveProvider` with the audio as it is received after decoding each MP3 frame to PCM.